# fullcalender skip month on adding validrange

Tags: jquery, date, skip

I want to skip 10 days from the current date in selection in fullcalender it works fine but when I click on next month it goes to direct march month from January and skipping February month.

Here is the code and line causing issue: `start:  nowDate.setDate(nowDate.getDate() +10`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var scheduled_occasionsEl = document.getElementById('occ');

    var scheduled_occasions = new FullCalendar.Calendar(scheduled_occasionsEl, {
      // initialDate: '2020-09-12',
      // editable: true,
      selectable: true,
      // businessHours: true,
      dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: <?php echo json_encode($calendar_events)?>,
      validRange: function(nowDate){
    return {start:  nowDate.setDate(nowDate.getDate() +10)} //to prevent anterior dates
},
    });
    scheduled_occasions.render();
  });
// });
</script>
```

Comment: Depending on the `FullCalendar` version, you _may_ be able to do: `start: moment().add(10, 'days')`

Comment: getting an error: moment is not defined
and version is FullCalendar v5.3.2

Comment: Moment is bundled with fullcalendar, since [v3](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/moment)... see if this tweak makes any difference: `start: $.fullcalendar.moment().add(10, 'days')`  Note, I've _not_ used fullcalendar myself, just took a quick glance at their documentation.

Comment: hello paul i added moment.js after main js of fullcander and used your code but it still says moment is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it wihout moment js using doc link given here
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/visibleRange

```
validRange: function(nowDate){
 var startDate = new Date(nowDate.valueOf());
 startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 10); 

   return {start:  startDate} //to prevent anterior dates
},
```